# (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output) sent message telegram

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

i'm make a new shell script crontab notify to telegram but the message doesn't received

environment
ubuntu 16.04

```
uname -n >> text.txt
while read p; do
  adb -s "$p" shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer >> text.txt
  adb -s "$p" shell dumpsys battery | grep level >> text.txt
  adb -s "$p" shell getprop ro.product.model >> text.txt
  adb -s "$p" shell dumpsys battery | grep health >> text.txt
  TEXT=$(cat text.txt)
curl -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage -d chat_id=<chat id> -d text="$TEXT"
  rm text.txt
done <info.txt
```

i expect the message can be received in telegram

this log cron

```
cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-03-25 17:53:44 WIB; 11min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 14599 (cron)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 3.3M
      CPU: 229ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─14599 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Mar 25 18:02:01  -Latitude-3490 CRON[14811]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 25 18:02:01  -Latitude-3490 CRON[14812]: (root) CMD (sh /home/asd/device_info.sh)
Mar 25 18:02:01  -Latitude-3490 CRON[14811]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 25 18:03:01  -Latitude-3490 CRON[14857]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 25 18:03:01  -Latitude-3490 CRON[14858]: (root) CMD (sh /home/asd/device_info.sh)
Mar 25 18:03:01 -Latitude-3490 CRON[14857]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 25 18:04:01 -Latitude-3490 CRON[14866]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 25 18:04:01 -Latitude-3490 CRON[14867]: (root) CMD (sh /home/asd/device_info.sh)
Mar 25 18:05:01 -Latitude-3490 CRON[14879]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 25 18:05:01 -Latitude-3490 CRON[14880]: (root) CMD (sh /home/asd/device_info.sh)
```

Comment: how many serial numbers of device you collected in `$p`?   
how do you write this job in `crontab`?  
do you have any mailer in your system?  
  
i tested and fix your script and also need to know job executing command.

Comment: 2 serial device.  i write at /etc/crontab `*  *    * * *   root    /home/bukalapak/device_info.sh`. if i run use `sh device_info.sh` thats running

Comment: i use postfix service

Comment: `root`? for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150556

this is quick issue for your case.

for one mobile device serial number:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERIAL="XX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
TOKEN="XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
CHATID="XXXXXXXXX"

# stuff
MSG="*server hostname:*
$(uname -n)

*mobile device info:*
$(adb -s "$SERIAL" shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer)
$(adb -s "$SERIAL" shell getprop ro.product.model)
$(adb -s "$SERIAL" shell dumpsys battery | grep -Eo '(level|health).*' )"

curl -s https://api.telegram.org/bot"$TOKEN"/sendMessage \  
     -d "chat_id=$CHATID&text=$MSG&parse_mode=markdown" > /dev/null
# end stuff
```

for whitespace separated serials in `devices.txt` file you should add

```
...

for SERIAL in $(cat devices.txt)
  do
  # stuff
  ...
  ...
  # end stuff
  done
```

add job to `crontab`

```
 * * * * * exec /root/get_device_info
```

result:
[image]

Comment: why MSG can get value? i got 400 because the message is empty

Comment: why empty? can you show real code and usage? what are you mean when start script with `root _script_`?

Comment: this is fully working example. i has been write it few hours ago.